# Ошибка при импорте базы данных

Tags: mysql

Ребят, подскажите, импортировала на локальный хост базу данных с боевого хоста, по началу из-за большого размера копировала около 20 минут, потом выдал ошибку SQL-запрос:

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT* /;

Ответ MySQL:

```
Документация
#1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

С бубном вокруг нее уже поплясала, удалить строчку удаляла, оставляла только строчку "SET NAMES utf8", в общем, эксперементировала по полной. Может, есть ещё идеи, как с этим безобразием справиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь консолью.

> you can restore the info to the database again using:
>
> mysql -h hostname -u user --password=password databasename < filename

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,195091,195097

Comment: Нужно перед импортом БД удалить из дампа строки, содержащие
/*!40101